# passing a array to php via ajax?

Tags: jquery

I have this array

```
var car = new Array();
car['brand'] = "Ford";
car['color'] = "red";
car['type'] = 1;
```

now, i tried sending this but php only tells me car is a undefined index:

```
$.post('regCar.php', { "car[]": car }, function(data) {

    // some other lol here ...

});
```

Sending in `"car[]": ["Ford", "red", 1]` works fine :( How can i pass in an associative array to php?

Comment: [Don't use arrays this way, use objects.](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Associative_Arrays#Associative_Arrays). Make a `print_r($_POST)` and see what you get.

Comment: you are sending data from php to ajax but your title is reverse of that

Comment: @diEcho: No, he is sending the data with jQuery to a PHP script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you [should not use arrays this way](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Associative_Arrays#Associative_Arrays). Only use arrays for **numerical** indexes:

> Associative `Arrays` are not allowed... or more precisely you are not allowed to use non number indexes for arrays. If you need a map/hash use `Object` instead of `Array` in these cases because the features that you want are actually features of `Object` and not of `Array`. `Array` just happens to extend `Object` (like any other object in JS and therefore you might as well have used `Date`, `RegExp` or `String`).

This is exactly the reason why the code does not work.

[Have a look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93ncL/1/): The alert is empty meaning that jQuery is not serializing (and therefore sending) any data at all.

One might expect that it would at least send an empty value, like `car[]=` but apparently it does not.

If you use an object:

```
var car = {};
```

[it works](http://jsfiddle.net/93ncL/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Read [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: *now, i tried sending this but php only tells me car is a **undefined index*** ... you got the question the wrong way.

Comment: what? i've ran a print_r on $_POST, it's empty! 'regCar.php', {'car': car}, function(data) is the syntax :(

Comment: @Jason94: Where do you define `car`? Could you please post more of your code? Is `car` accessible from where you call `$.post`? What does `console.log(car)` just before the Ajax call give you? However, the problem could really be that you are using an array instead of an object.

Comment: Because he wants to send data from  jQuery to PHP and sending `car` does not work. The PHP functions will not help him here either.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $.post('regCar.php', {'car': car}, function(data) { // - I changed the key value name
    });
```

You don't need to add the brackets in the data parameter

However, I recommend you use JS objects.

```
var car = {};
car.brand = "Ford";
car.color = "red";
car.type = 1;
```

If you're getting an undefined error on the PHP side, you'll need to post your PHP code.

**EDIT**

As @Felix Kling points out, dropping array in favor of objects will work for you.

Comment: @Felix, looks like it. I read somewhere that JS doesn't actually have associated arrays and that it silently converts to objects. So objects seem to be the way to go